# How to make this image translates to top?

Tags: beamer

How to make this image translates to top by 2cm ? Using yshift or how, please ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I cannot use tikz beacause Im' trying to display the image's caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the **\vspace** command, which produces vertical space, with a negative value, your figure will go up.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

use  `\begin{frame}[t]` and the image will be on top of the frame